# Data Converion from arrays to maps

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am Creating a list of Cars with their properties (name, model, cost) and converting it into a format so that for a given car name retrieval of its model and cost value is fast

```
const cars =  [{name: 'Maruthi Dzire', model: '2017', cost:500000},{ name: 'Ford', model: '2019', cost:100000}
];


const getCarDetails = (cars,name) => {

    var carDetails={};

        carDetails = cars
        .filter(item=>item.name===name)
        .map(item => item);     

    return carDetails;
};

console.log(getCarDetails(cars,'Ford'));
```

Output:{ name: "Ford", model: "2019", cost: 100000 }

I am looking for different result

Expected Output: {model: "2019", cost: 100000}

Please advice.

Comment: based on the car name i want retrieve remaining two values. As i am sending 'Ford' as the input i would like retrive only model and cost of the  'Ford'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the map to only return the keys your need

```
.map(item => ({ model: item.model, cost: item.cost }))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have single car with name `ford` in an array 
then you can use function of JS like find, findIndex or filter

Better would be to explore it:

```
let fordCar =  cars.find(car => car.name === 'Ford')
delete fordCar.name;
```

it will result : `{cost: 100000, model: "2019"}`

you can do this if you have `multiple cars` with `name` `Ford`:

```
let exceptFordCArs = cars.filter(car => car.name === 'Ford').map(car => delete car.name && car)
```

it will result : `[{"model":"2019","cost":100000},{"model":"2020","cost":110000}]`